# how do i display a widget in a Frame written in another script Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a two python scripts with two classes. How do i display a widget which exists in the second script to the a frame in the first script for example

I have the main script where i have my frames in the first script. in the second script(Toplevel) i ran some functions to perform some tasks. after the tasks are performed, the results are written to the database. 
while the tasks are running, i wanted a progress bar to be displayed in the Main so that after the tasks is finished then the progress bar can stop.

the challenge is the condition used to start and stop the progressbar occurs in the second script. but i want the progressbar to be displayed in the main

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#import script2

class Main(object):
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master = master
        #main frames
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.mainFrame.pack()

        self.topFrame= Frame(self.mainFrame,width=200,height =150, bg="#f8f8f8",padx =20, relief =SUNKEN,
                        borderwidth=2)
        self.topFrame.pack(side=TOP,fill = X)

        self.btnseldate = Button(self.topFrame, text="open script2", font="arial 12 bold")
        self.btnseldate.configure(compound=LEFT, command=self.sc)
        self.btnseldate.pack()

    def sc(self):
        s = script2.class2(self.master,self.mainFrame)

def main():
    root =Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    root.title("two variables")
    root.geometry("200x200+350+200")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

this is the second script

```
####In the second script titled "script2.py"

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class class2(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self,parent, mainFrame):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("200x200+350+200")
        self.title("display")

        #object1 = script1.Main()
        #self.script1Frame = object1.topFrame()

        ##this button should be displayed just under the first button in script 1 
        self.progbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.topFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200)
        self.progbar.pack()
        self.progbar.config(mode='determinate')
        self.progbar.start()
        self.self.topFrame.pack()

        #this is a dummy function just to describe what i have
        def funcdotask():
        #this function contains so many local variables that are only known in 
        #this script
            pass
```

so the widget actually depends on a condition in the second script , thats why i didn't just place it in the first script. 
i need ideas on even how i inherit variables from script2 to script 1 for example
or if there is a way i can get the results from the performed function in script 1(Main). it could help

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Try using `import` keyword wisely.

Comment: ***`object1 = script1.Main()`***:This will fail. with undefined `script1`. Why do you want to insert `Main` into a `Toplevel`?

Comment: because i wanted to display a progressbar in Main even though the functions that control the progressbar where in script2

Comment: Change to `s = script2.class2(self.master, self.mainFrame)`=> `def __init__(self, parent, mainFrame):` => `Progressbar(mainFrame, ...`

Comment: i tried adding ```` def __init__(self, parent, mainFrame): => Progressbar(mainFrame, ...````  there was no change. is there something i'm missing

Comment: done. example edited

Comment: There are multiple issues: **1.** You don't call `def sc(...`? **2.** Indentation error at `def sc(....`. **3.** There is no `self.mainFrame` defined. **4.** Invalid argument `.geometry("200 x 200")`. **5.** Invalid argument `Button(topFrame`

Comment: i have done the editing again.. so the objective is to show the widget written in script two, on self.topFrame in script1

Comment: Read my comment again, you get undefined at `Progressbar(self.topFrame...`. See: [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/AustereDapperParameter)

Comment: so how do i define the self.mainFrame. because at this point i do not know what next to do